# Wget or Curl usage. How to download all "index.html" files based on regexp'ed address

Tags: curl, wget

I'm stuck with simple task. Here is pseudocode of what I am trying to do:

```
wget -i https://somesite/jobs/companies/*/addresses/index.html -o myfolder
```

The above pseudocode should put all company's addresses in my folder. Structure of address is always the same: `https://somesite/jobs/companies/<SOMECOMPANY>/addresses/`. What I need is somehow tell wget, or curl if you wish, to download files based on pattern.

What I've tried so far:

```
wget -spider -r --user-agent="wget" --accept-regex=".*?/companies/.*?/addresses/.*?\.html" https://jobs.somesite.com/companies/
```

The `-spider` option tells wget to not download anything. For now, the only file `wget` have fetched, have `jobs.somesite.com/companies/index.html` address.

The question is. How to make the list of company's addresses with the above schema?

Comment: Most sites block remote directory listings over HTTP for security reasons so you might need FTP access or to use a web crawler to find links in pages.  Even then, if the site uses a CMS the index pages might not really exist, they might be dynamically generated from a database.

Comment: @DaveS I have to admit that `wget -r <address>` gets site structure perfectly. I just don't want to download all files.

Comment: That's because -r retrieves and parses the HTML + CSS, so it's acting as a web crawler: https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Recursive-Download

Answer (score 0):

Either I made a mistake in my `regexp` string or `wget` `--accept-regex` do not understands file extension filter.

The command that accepts and downloads full list is:

```
wget -m --user-agent="wget" -A="html" --regex-type=pcre --accept-regex=".*?/companies/.*?/offices/" https://jobs.somesite.com/companies/
```

Still the site supplies a dynamic list of companies. So only part of the list was downloaded **:P**

Comment: Is this the answer to your question?

Comment: @emix Yes. Dynamic fetch will be another question.